# Is it possible for a 'foreach' loop to have a condition check?

Tags: c#, foreach

If I have a `foreach` loop, is there any way to check a boolean as well?

I don't want to check once inside the `foreach()` and then break for example. I want to `foreach` over a collection and at the same time evaluate if something is true.

For example, I don't want to do:

```
    IEnumerable<Job> jobs = currentJobs;

    foreach(Job job in jobs)
    {
        if (found) 
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? I'm a little fuzzy on what you mean...which means other people are probably confused as well.

Comment: Could you provide more details and/or an example?

Comment: you mean something like foreach (var item in MyList.Where(condition))

Comment: you have wide imagination. please provide an example of what you mean.

Comment: I think that's what while() { .. } is for. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd(VS.71).aspx

Comment: You realize that whether the boolean evaluation is part of the loop declaration or if it is an `if` statement that breaks at the beginning of the loop, they are functionally the same, right?

Comment: I think you're looking for one of `TakeWhile`, `First` or `FirstOrDefault`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx

Comment: Right. I'm clear on what you don't want to do. I haven't a clue about what you do want to do though.

Comment: I updated my question to better fit your needs. I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could always turn it into a for loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < jobs.Count && booleanTrue; i++) {
 // do a lot of great stuff
}
```

You would also need to change jobs from `IEnumerable` to `IList`. I think `IList` would serve your purposes better. `IEnumerable` lazy evaluates the elements just before you need them and doesn't include the associated collection helper methods.

Comment: You can only do this if the collection provides a `Count` property (and presumably also an indexer since "do a lot of great stuff" will likely need to involve accessing the elements by index). The example in the question uses `IEnumerable<Job>` which doesn't have either.

Comment: Ah, okay. He didn't have that example posted when I responded. I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score 42):

I found another approach:

```
        foreach (var car in cars) if (!rentedCars.Contains(car))
        {
            // Magic
        }
```

Comment: I think this should be the answer. Still this is what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is just single-statement control flow; i.e., just an `if` statement nested in a `foreach` with no brackets.

Comment: what if cars == null -> exception

Answer (score 26):

Try using [TakeWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx).

From the example:

```
    string[] fruits = { "apple", "banana", "mango", "orange", 
                          "passionfruit", "grape" };

    IEnumerable<string> query =
        fruits.TakeWhile(fruit => String.Compare("orange", fruit, true) != 0);

    foreach (string fruit in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fruit);
    }

        /*
         This code produces the following output:

         apple
         banana
         mango
        */
```

Answer (score 15):

Not hugely loving it, but maybe some LINQ?

```
bool yourBool = false;
foreach(var item in
    collection.TakeWhile(x => yourBool))
{...}
```

?

Comment: That simulates a continue, not a break.

Comment: @Henk - and to be fair, until the example was added the intent was ambiguous.

Answer (score 11):

Am I understanding correctly that you

1. have a sequence of elements
2. want to take some action with each element
3. but you want to break on the first element you encounter for which some condition is true?

I don't understand the resistance to using `foreach` loops; I would either stick with what you have or

```
foreach(var job in jobs.TakeWhile(x => someCondition(x)) { 
    someAction(job);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, a foreach  simply works for each element.

You can combine multiple conditions in a regular `for(a; b; c)` loop. Like `for(a; b && x; c)`